# Heroku conflict between gzipping assets and precompiling assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, gzip

I've been running a Rails 3.1 app on Heroku Cedar Stack for a couple of months now. I'm using Rack::Deflater middleware to gzip my content and achieve this by

```
config.middleware.insert_before ActionDispatch::Static, Rack::Deflater
```

in my staging.rb file.

However, since last week, I get the following error when deploying to Heroku

```
Running: rake assets:precompile
   rake aborted!
   No such middleware to insert before: ActionDispatch::Static
```

However, running rake middleware still returns

```
use Rack::Cache
use Rack::Deflater
use ActionDispatch::Static
use Rack::Lock
```

And content served were still gzipped. However, assets were not compiled(minified) as pre-compilation failed. A manual rake precompile::asets also does not help.

So, I'm assuming ActionDispatch::Static is not available during pre-compilation of assets. So I tried to insert Rack::Deflater before Rack::Lock and now my assets are compiled without any error message but content served is not gzipped.

So, what do I need to do, to both gzip and compile my assets? What am I missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Just a heads up `Rack::Deflater` [is already used by Rails 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8152626/rackdeflater-apparently-gzip-page-but-it-appears-as-gibberish-in-browser/8155058#8155058) so you don't need to manually do this.

BUT, to answer your problem here, I would assume that your `production.rb` has `config.serve_static_assets = false` set.

the `ActionDispatch::Static` middleware is only used when `serve_static_assets` is set to `true`.  Heroku actually injects this config to override whatever you set anyway (see the `Injecting rails3_serve_static_assets` log message when you deploy), but I'm not sure at what stage in the deploy this happens.

So it's likely that you don't have static asset serving enabled when the `assets:precompile` runs (note this is just a guess, I'm not on Rails 3.1 yet so I could be wrong)

I would recommend against membLoper's suggestion of adding it manually in your rackup file:

1. it's not needed as explained above
2. your middleware that is relevant to your app should really be injected as you had originally tried in your `application.rb`

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the case. Can you point to the primary source?

Answer (score 3):

I still dont understand why Heroku does not recognize ActionDispatch::Static during pre-compilation of assets. However, Heroku folks did suggest a workaround to this issue.

The Rack::Deflater middleware needs to inserted in config.ru file rather than environment files. Something like,

```
require ::File.expand_path('../config/environment',  __FILE__)
# Middleware to gzip content
use Rack::Deflater
run MyApplication
```

This way, it does not interfere with assets pre-compilation and still gzips the content being served.

Any resource on how config.ru works and where Rack::Deflater now resides is very welcome.

Comment: This is cool, but not as cool as serving the .gz file the asset pipeline creates. I wonder if there is any way to do that?

Comment: Here is [a related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12326191/any-way-to-serve-gzip-assets-from-heroku) you may find helpful.