# Rack::Deflater apparently gzip page but it appears as gibberish in browser

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rack, cedar

I've deployed a rails 3.1 app on the new cedar stack on heroku.
The new stack doesn't automatically provide gzipping so I've added

`use Rack::Deflater` in my *config.ru*

Testing it through curl with the following command:

```
curl -i -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate' http://carbuzz-production.herokuapp.com
```

Returns an header with `content encoding` `gzip` and a body that seems compressed.
Opening the page in firefox or chrome shows the body untranslated (lots of gibberish).

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bit silly. Apparently rails 3.1 automatically uses Rack::Deflater so I was basically gzipping twice...

I discovered it by executing rake middleware.

I hope it helps anyway.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the case with Rails 3.2 on Heroku Cedar, I'm not getting gzipped output by default.

Comment: I'm not getting gzipped output either with config.serve_static_assets = false