# Any way to serve gzip assets from heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, gzip, asset-pipeline, rack

I'm wondering if there is any way to get the Rails webserver (thin) to serve the ***.gz** files the asset pipeline creates. As I understand, those have a higher compression level than that of `Rack::Deflater`, which only works with `serve_static_assets` from within the rackup file and not in `config.middleware`.

A less optimal solution might be to change the default compression level of `Zlib` which is what `Rack::Deflater` references. It should only need to gzip once, then it goes to `Rack::Cache`, then hopefully a CDN.

A second less optimal solution might be a `Rack::Rewrite`.

Comment: Someone made a middleware that appears to do what you want: https://gist.github.com/2152663

Comment: the asset pipeline compiles .gz files as well as regular files, I think pushing that to heroku should work, rack shouldn't have to deflate anything, just serve a .gz instead of a regular asset.

Comment: Which is why the gist above does exactly what I need.

Comment: Another option for serving gzipped assets using Rack::Rewrite https://gist.github.com/eliotsykes/6049536

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer to your question can be found at https://gist.github.com/2152663.

Comment: To summarize the answer: Use this gem https://github.com/mattolson/heroku_rails_deflate

Answer (score 0):

Use this `gem github.com/mattolson/heroku_rails_deflate`