# How to modify Rails middleware to serve gzip assets from Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

My question is closely related to "[any way to serve gzip assests from Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12326191/any-way-to-serve-gzip-assets-from-heroku)"

The best approach points to a Gist: https://gist.github.com/2152663 
So, how do I make it work? It seems obvious for the person who asked, but I'm having a hard time putting it together.

I understand I have to place `compressed_static_assets.rb` into **/lib** and then reference it from my `production.rb`, but I keep getting the error: **"uninitialized constant Middleware (NameError)"**

Comment: Just out of curiosity, if you're trying to serve assets from Heroku, have you investigated [AssetSync](https://github.com/rumblelabs/asset_sync)? It sort of solves most of the problems you're encountering.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Veraticus. Actually, I was looking for a simpler solution, but I will keep that way in mind.

Answer (score 0):

This might be an older question but did you try the [heroku-deflater gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/heroku-deflater)? Looks like it does the same thing but is easier to get up and running.

Comment: heroku-deflater is for configuring Rack::Deflater to compress arbitrary responses from the app. a good asset configuration will generate compressed versions of the assets at deploy time, so after that it's just a matter of rails serving the correct version if the client asks for it. (im not sure how to do this)